# Securely renewing a session without javascript and without breaking CSRF protection

Tags: security, session, csrf, legacy

I am working on doing some security hardening on a legacy web application, and have run into a bit of a conflict.

So, I added CSRF protection to the application with a CSRF token as a hidden input in forms. Pretty normal.

Then I dramatically lowered the session timeout (the previous value was 8 hours, which obviously is unacceptable from a security point of view). However, to prevent users from losing their work when their session times out, I also implemented a modal login dialog with some JavaScript to renew their session before completing the form submission. This JavaScript also updates the CSRF token input with the new value from the server upon a successful login, as obviously the old CSRF token was associated with their previous now-expired session. Losing work is a huge deal for this application because users will genuinely spend a hour on a single page, just filling out data in a form and never hitting the save button, all the while the server doesn't know that the users are doing anything.

However, there is a not-insignificant portion of our userbase on machines with some pretty draconian policies forbidding JavaScript entirely. So, a secondary workaround is also needed for these people. If I were building the application from scratch, I feel the best solution for these users would be to simply re-populate all the inputs on the page they were on (prior to the timeout) with values from the POST data (after the user logs back in). However, implementing that would be such a gargantuan undertaking in this old code that it may as well be impossible.

We really had a hard time coming up with a workable solution for the non-JavaScript users. The best I've been able to come up with is to place a fixed link in the corner of the screen informing the user of when their session would expire, and redirecting them to the login page in a new tab if they click the link. That way, they can click the link and log in again before submitting the form. However, that breaks the CSRF protection, as upon returning to the form the CSRF token in the hidden input no longer matches the one in new session.

Short of refactoring literally thousands for forms, is there any way I can keep users without JavaScript from losing work when their session expires, without breaking CSRF protection?

Comment: Since the root cause of the problem you described is CSRF tokens being effectively short-lived in line with the lifespan of short-lived sessions, the most obvious solution would be to give CSRF tokens a longer lifespan not bound to that of sessions. 
Provided you can analyze the security threats and conclude the security impact from having the combination of long-lived CSRF token and short-lived session is marginal.

Comment: If the CSRF token is not associated with a specific session, how does one prevent an attacker from obtaining their own CSRF token by visiting a page in the application, then using that token in a form on their own site to commit CSRF? If the user visited the evil site an submitted the form, it would have a valid session ID from the cookies, and a valid CSRF token in the POST data. How do you prevent that without associating the two?

Answer (score 1):

#### Theory

> If the CSRF token is not associated with a specific session, how does one prevent an attacker from obtaining their own CSRF token by visiting a page in the application, ...

One does not attempt to prevent an attacker from obtaining their own CSRF token. CSRF protection does not rely on attacker's inability to obtain and submit a valid CSRF token. CSRF protection depends on two CSRF tokens and relies on attacker's inability to obtain and submit back to the server two tokens that are related to each other. In practice, "related to each other" means "cryptographically bound to each other".

An attacker can obtain a valid CSRF token and maybe could even additionally obtain the second CSRF token which is also valid on its own. However the attacker won't be able to ensure both tokens are cryptographically bound to each other.

#### Implementation

There are many protection schemes. For example, looking at the high level like this:

1. The server creates two CSRF tokens and sends both to the client along with the session cookie. The first CSRF token is sent as a cookie (let's call it 'form cookie'), the second one is sent as the hidden form input you are currently using.
2. The server has a symmetric key that is never sent out, let's call it 'server key'. To create a form cookie, the server generates a random sequence of bytes (let's call it 'CSRF_key') and encrypts it using the server key. The encrypted output, serialised as a string, is sent to the client in the form cookie.
3. The server creates a string by concatenating the current timestamp and a GUID: `timestamp+GUID`. It then calculates a hash of that string using HMAC algorithm: `HMAC(timestamp+GUID, CSRF_key)`. HMAC requires a key as the second argument and the server uses CSRF_key generated at the previous step as the HMAC key. The HMAC output is serialised as a string and concatenated with the `timestamp+GUID` string. The concatenation is sent out as the second CSRF cookie e.g. your hidden form input.

When the server gets POST with the form, it gets both CSRF tokens (one as a form cookie, another as an hidden input). It first checks the session, then it verifies that the timestamp (taken from the `timestamp+GUID` string) is valid e.g not too stale, not in the future etc. Then the server uses the server key to decrypt the form cookie and get the CSRF_key.

The next step: Calculate HMAC of the `timestamp+GUID` string using CSRF_key as the HMAC key. Compare the output with HMAC value in the hidden field. If identical, then CSRF check is ok so accept the form and generate another CSRF_key to be used as the 'form cookie' for the next form.

Note: In many real life scenarious the implementation is an overkill and could be simplified. Also it's a high level blueprint, there are important low level implementation details like sufficient keys length, proper cookie attributes etc.