# Is it a security concern to allow a client to generate a CSRF token at login time, usable by the client upon the next request?

Tags: security, csrf

For background, this question is the result of my brainstorming for a solution to this other question: [Securely renewing a session without javascript and without breaking CSRF protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70703895/securely-renewing-a-session-without-javascript-and-without-breaking-csrf-protect)

I've had a thought, but I'm not sure if it's secure or not. Does the following seem exploitable in any way?

At the time of login the client sends a pseudo-random string (which is actually the "old" csrf token from the user's previous session, to refer to the previous question) alongside the username and password. The server then associates that csrf token with that particular client for the next request. The user would then get a new CSRF token to use from the server. Essentially, if a CSRF token is initially set by a client during authentication, is it safe to use that same token to validate that same client on a subsequent request, with the token taking not one but two full round trips?

I had initially assumed that would be insecure, but the more I think about it, I really can't think of an exploit. The token would be sent alongside the credentials, so an attacker couldn't set the CSRF token unless they also had the username and password, in which case security is already compromised. Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: If not using the old CSRF token what other mechanisms exist to identify the client?

Comment: This is taking place after a session expiration, so the client is being identified by their username and password.

Comment: then why reuse the token at all; if at the point you identify by their old CSRF token then you can identify by their user/pass details?

Comment: The intent is that the user has a form filled out in another tab. They want to submit the form, but their session has expired. We need to re-authenticate them but still keep the same CSRF token so that form can be submitted.

Comment: You may get better traction with this question and existing answers [**here**](https://security.stackexchange.com/.)

Comment: Right, but server-side the token must be associated with a session, and that session can and should expire. So, the CSRF token lifetime is limited by the lifetime of it's associated session. I did not realize there was a separate site for security questions, I'll post there too.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of thought and research, I thought of an exploit to this method: evil.com hosts a phishing website with a form set to post an attacker-controlled "old" CSRF token to the session renewal endpoint. The user logs in like normal on the session renewal endpoint. Now the CSRF token has been set to an attacker-controlled value. Then the attacker can proceed with a normal CSRF attack. Basically, the attacker has to do not one but two CSRF attacks, but it's exploitable nonetheless.

So, bad idea, don't do this. For new code, obviously there would be no reason to do this anyway, there are better solutions. Jury is still out on what to do instead for my particular situation where those solutions would require basically re-writing thousands of forms, but regardless this is not the way.